# DioError Http status error [401] while displaying data

Tags: flutter, api

I'm trying to display data from the API to the screen, but I can't do it because of the 401 error, take a look at my code and tell me what exactly is wrong, I think that I wrote the API incorrectly. At the moment I am trying to find the information myself, but I think the problem is in the API, and if so, what exactly is the problem?

Code :

API:

```dart
    class ApiService {
     Dio dio = new Dio();

     var token ="token";
      var refresh_token ="token";
   

     Future getUserCards() async {
       try {
         Response resp;

        var get_cards = "https://example/api/cards";
         resp = await dio.get(get_cards);
         dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${token}";
         dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";
         var json = (resp.data);
         var value = json["id"]["row"]["seq_num"]["text"];
         return value;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  

     Future loginUser(String username, String password) async {
       var storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
       await storage.write(key: 'JWT', value: token);

       var login = "https://example/users/login/";

    final data = {"username": username, "password": password};

    Response response;
    response = await dio.post(login, data: data);

    dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer ${token}";
    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Get.to(CardScreen());
      return response.data;
    } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      var refreshToken = await dio.post(
          "https://example.api/cards/refresh/");

      response = await dio.post(refresh_token, data: data);

      dio.options.headers["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer ${token},'Content-Type': 'application/json','refresh_token': '$refresh_token'";

      storage = response.data["token"];
      refresh_token = response.data["refresh_token"];

      return loginUser("username", "password");
    } else
      return null;
  }
}
```

UI :

```dart
children: [
           Expanded(
               child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
             future: ApiService().getUserCards(),
             builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
               if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                 return Center(
                   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                 );
               } else {
                 return ListView.builder(
                     itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       return Card(
                         child: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                       );
                     });
               }
             },
           )
```

Comment: 401 is error from your API side not in flutter

Comment: I know, i didnt say thats the error was on the flutter side

Comment: so now what do you actually want to know?

Comment: I know the problem is in the API, but where exactly? Tokens? Maybe headers or requests? Maybe with the logic of the program?

Comment: the problem could be in header as well because 401 error belongs to unauthorized user. check whether you are passing correct token in header

Comment: I will check it out

Comment: sure you can mark as useful once it worked for you. Thanks